# Datastax DevCenter 1.4.1 - Turn Off Trace

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nosql

Is there any way to turn off/disable "Query Trace" in Datastax DevCenter 1.4.1?

We don't want it running for every query.

Answer (score 0):

DevCenter enables query tracing only for the last query executed (the one whose results are presented in the results view). While it's currently not possible to disable it, the next version of DevCenter will include an advanced setting for disabling it.

(*Note*: I'd really appreciate if you could provide here or privately more details about why you'd like to disable query tracing. You can contact me: alexp @ datastax.com)

Comment: DevCenter version 1.5.0 and higher have a way to disable the query trace feature. From the Readme file:  
Q: Is there any way to disable Query Tracing?  
A: By default, DevCenter enables query tracing only for the last query      executed in a script. A system property can be used to control this by    adding the following like to the DevCenter config.ini file:   devcenter.querytrace.enabled=false  
The config.ini file is located in:  

Mac: <DevCenter_Home>/configuration  
Linux: <DevCenter_Home>/configuration  
Windows: <DevCenter_Home>/configuration